# Can I load images synchronously with Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I know it isn't very practical to load bitmaps from the device storage synchronously, but I really have to do it. I haven't figured out any way to do this.

Comment: I figure they could not see a usecase where that would be necessary.

Comment: *but I really have to do it.* would you mind elaborating a little bit on this point ?

Comment: I use a library and one of its method is responsible for managing a notification. There's a function I have to implement and it returns a notification for the library. I use a RemoteView and it contains an ImageView, but because I can not modify the notification after it has been created, only if I recreate it, I have to "delay" the creation of the notification after the bitmap will have been loaded.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to do.  "From device storage" is vague. What format do you need it to take in memory upon completion?

Comment: I pass the uri of album arts (think about audio files) to Glide.

Comment: If you are doing work in WorkManager you need to make the code flow sync, but you could still also use a CountDownLatch.

Answer (score 50):

Yes is possible and is in [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads) documentation.

For example if you need to retrive the Bitmap synchronously you can do:

Glide V3:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = Glide.with(applicationContext)
.load(yourUrl)
.asBitmap()
.into(500, 500)
.get()
```

Glide v4:

```
FutureTarget<Bitmap> futureBitmap = Glide.with(applicationContext)
                           .asBitmap()
                           .load(yourURL)) 
                           .submit();
Bitmap myBitmap = futureBitmap.get();
```

Note: This code need to be run in the background or the app will crash.

Comment: If you do this on main thread it will throw an error saying you have to call this on another thread. Blocking the thread sure, but make sure its not the main thread.

Comment: that's v3 how bout v4.

Answer (score 0):

Using interfaces to load data after image is loaded is a better option.

Create a new file called OnglideLoaded.java file like this:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public interface OnGlideLoaded {
    void onGlideLoaded(Drawable drawable);
}
```

Now create setter method for it like this where glide is:

```
public void setOnGlideLoaded(OnGlideLoaded onGlideLoaded) {
    this.onGlideLoaded = onGlideLoaded;
}
```

Not call it inside Glide Target:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .asBitmap()
     .load(uri)
     .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
           @Override
           public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                 icon = resource;
                 if (onGlideLoaded!=null){
                        //This will send the image to every registered interface
                        onGlideLoaded.onGlideLoaded(icon);
                 }
           }

           @Override
           public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

           }
});
```

Now call the interface like this where you want the image:

```
reference.setOnGlideLoaded(new OnGlideLoaded() {
    @Override
    public void onGlideLoaded(Drawable drawable) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(drawable);
    }
});
```

> Here, reference will be the object where you created the setter method.