# How can I load a Bitmap synchronously with Glide?

Tags: java, android, synchronization, android-glide

I want to load the Arwork-Image into my Notification (with `MediaStyle`).

Using the following code crashes my app with the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on a
>   background thread

```
public Bitmap getAlbumArtwork(long albumID, int Height, int Width) {
    try {
        return Glide.with(mContext).load(getAlbumArtworkUri(albumID)).asBitmap().error(R.drawable.standardartwork).into(Width, Height).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'm also willing to change the library, e.g. to `UniversalImageLoader`, if necessary!

**Additionally**

I use this method to load the image for a notification... This notification is created in a service, so the ui will not be interrupted! As i have no ID of the notifications ImageView, I don't know how to set it in another way! 
Furthermore I need the Bitmap to add it to the MediaMetaData for the MediaSession.

Comment: you can force this method to run on ui thread. Although you should avoid that.

Comment: Did the answer help you ?

Comment: no, I returned to my old version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I load images synchronously with Glide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296718/can-i-load-images-synchronously-with-glide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You must call this method on a background thread

```
val bitmap = Glide.with(CONTEXT)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("URL")
            .submit().get()
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I load a Bitmap syncronously with Glide?

If you did intend to retrieve the network image from the Main thread (aka UI thread) , that would be a **bad** approach. Operations that take considerable time should be executed from a separate thread, or in the worse case it can even lead to an ANR (Application Not Responding) state.

If you need the `Bitmap` from Glide, you can retrieve it perfect in an asynchronous manner, this is how you do it:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load("http://example.com/imageurl")
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    // you can do something with loaded bitmap here

                    // .....

                    holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, my target server is a single thread embedded-device, so we need send request one by one. after some research I find this work for me.

```
public class GlideConfModule implements GlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        //The number "1" make things happen.
        builder.setResizeService(new FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor(1));
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {}
}
```

And done forget put this 'define' code to your Manifest.xml

```
        <application ...
        <meta-data
        android:name="path.to.your.GlideConfModule"
        android:value="GlideModule" />
```

BTW, I use Glide 3.x