# job scheduler with evernote/android-job library unsynchronized tasks

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-jobscheduler, android-job

hi i trying to add an ability to my app that user can activate a option to app change the phone background every 15 minutes but i have a problem im using [evernote/android-job library](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) and retrofit and the simple work of

```
public class WallpaperSyncJob extends Job {
    ArrayList<String> newString;
    public static final String TAG = "WallpaperSyncJob";
    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(@NonNull Params params) {
        final int min = 1;
        newString = new ArrayList<>();
        final int max = 10;
        final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        if (random == 3 && Prefs.getBoolean("selected_favorites",false)){
           ArrayList<Photo> photos = Helpers.getFavoritesList(MainApplication.getApp().getBoxStore());
            final int mMin = 0;
            final int mMax = photos.size();
            final int mRandom = new Random().nextInt((mMin - mMax) + 1) + mMin;
            GlideApp.with(getContext()).asBitmap().load(photos.get(mRandom).getImage()).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                            = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(resource);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else {
            String mSelected = Prefs.getString("selected_collections","");
            if (mSelected.length() != 0){
                String s = mSelected.replace("[","");
                String mS = s.replace("]","");
                 newString = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mS.split(",")));
            }
            RestClient.getApiService().getSelectedPhoto("http://test.com/site/getRandomSelected.php?collections="+Prefs.getString("selected_collections","")).enqueue(new Callback<Photo>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Photo> call, Response<Photo> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "response245", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: UnFavorite " + call.request().toString() );
                    GlideApp.with(getContext()).asBitmap().load(response.body().getImage()).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getContext());
                            try {
                                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(resource);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Photo> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: UnFavorite " + call.request().toString() );
                }
            });
        }
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }
    public static void scheduleJob() {
        Set<JobRequest> jobRequests = JobManager.instance().getAllJobRequestsForTag(WallpaperSyncJob.TAG);
        if (!jobRequests.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        PersistableBundleCompat extras = new PersistableBundleCompat();
        extras.putString("selected_collections",Prefs.getString("selected_collections","23"));
        extras.putBoolean("selected_favorites",Prefs.getBoolean("selected_favorites",false));
        int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(WallpaperSyncJob.TAG)
                .setExtras(extras)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
//                .startNow()
                .build()
                .schedule();


    }

    private void cancelJob(int jobId) {
        JobManager.instance().cancel(jobId);
    }
}
```

the code is work fine and do the work but i have a problem i want to reschedule the job in onFailure of retrofit i know i can do it with `return Result.RESCHEDULE;`
 but i dont know how return this value on onFailure 
**UPDATE** i tried this too and its not working :

```
private boolean test(){
    try {
        Response<Photo> response = RestClient.getApiService().getSelectedPhoto("http://test.com/site/getRandomSelected.php?collections="+Prefs.getString("selected_collections","")).execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()){
            FutureTarget<Bitmap> futureBitmap = Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(response.body().getImage()).submit();
            if (futureBitmap.isDone()){
                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(futureBitmap.get());
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (ExecutionException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and this the AsyncTask `private class Task extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return test();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform your requests in a synchronous way:

- for Retrofit use `.execute()` instead of `.enqueue()`
- for Glide see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952824/321354

Comment: hi thanks for helping me i tried this and its not working can you please help me? my update is on the question