# Glide inconsistent loading in for loop

Tags: android, android-glide

I am writing an Android app where I want to display a consistent stream using the newest Glide 4.11.0. My idea was that I display every 100 ms a new image using a for loop where I call the Glide function. When I start my function `loadImageFromURL()` it runs through and afterwards display all the images as fast as possible after each other, but I want to get it displayed evenly with a time gap of around 100 ms.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a problem with an internal thread of Glide?

My Code:

```
public void loadImageFromURL() {
        Glide.get(this).setMemoryCategory(MemoryCategory.HIGH); //use more RAM than normal
        final long Start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; imageNumber++) {         //for loop for displaying continuously stream
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > Start + i * 100) {
                Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(ImageURL).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).override(ScreenSizeX, ScreenSizeY).into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        _imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        imageNumber++;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                    }
                });
                i++;
            }
        }
    Glide.get(this).setMemoryCategory(MemoryCategory.NORMAL); //RAM usage back to normal
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple flaws with your code. Glide downloads the images in a separate thread, so it's running the download code independently from your loop. Some issues:

1. You are manipulating `imageNumber` from multiple threads. This will cause random time-sensitive issues. You should not increment `imageNumber` in `onResourceReady`
2. The loop will just infinitely loop until the desired time is reached. This will cause heavy CPU load and can be solved by using locks, waits or similar.

My suggestion: Try loading each image after another synchronously with the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952824/2232127). When an image has loaded, calculate how much time remains for your "image load break" to pass and use `Thread.sleep(milliSeconds)` to wait out the remaining time. Then you can update the imageView.

Make sure you run this code in a separate thread and use `runOnUIThread` when updating the imageView.

You can probably further optimize this by using a ConcurrentQueue where the download of the images all happen at once and a separate consumer thread takes from the queue and waits in between. This will probably have higher memory usage though because the images will be also stored in the queue.